# Why the need to mount a partition with nosuid when noexec is present?

Tags: linux, security, partitioning

I am using Fedora Core. I am to create a partition /data where users post some data (all have r+w permissions). Hence, for security purposes, I have to make it non-executable.

I understand from Linux security that `noexec` and `nosuid` must both be enabled for /data during mounting. I understand `noexec` and have it enabled. However I don't have `nosuid` enabled.

Any reason why both `noexec` and `nosuid` should be enabled for /data? Doesn't having just `noexec` suffice - since the users would not be able to run scripts and other programs, and `nosuid` does not matter?

Comment: You would think so [that `nosuid` is redundant], yes. Can you cite any reference that recommended that you needed to enable `nosuid` even though `noexec` was already enabled?

Comment: Actually I have seen that everywhere. Even CIS benchmarks state nosuid to be a different check on /tmp partition. Other references are just by googling: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/opensource/secure-temporary-files-in-linux/171

Comment: I have to guess that they're just being safe: so if you forget to set `noexec` at least you've still got `nosuid`. It's a weak argument though since both flags are configured in the same place, so if you forget one you're likely to forget the other one too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the `mount` man page

> noexec
>
> Do not allow direct execution of any binaries on the mounted filesystem. (Until recently it was possible to run binaries anyway using a command like /lib/ld*.so /mnt/binary. This trick fails since Linux 2.4.25 / 2.6.0.)

So, this looks like it's old advice from when `noexec` didn't stop all binaries from running; at least they weren't run with root privileges.

Comment: If you ran the executable with that trick, would it have gotten set-uid permissions?

Comment: The *Securing Debian Manual* has more information on this issue: [Mounting partitions the right way](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/securing-debian-manual/ch04s10.en.html)